# About objects that are members of classes

Tags: c++, constructor

I have the following code snippet:

```
class A{
    int i;
    public: A(int x): i(x) {}
    int get_i() { return i; }
};

class B{
    A a;
    int j;
public:
    B(int x, A y) { j = x; a = y; } // <--
    int get_j() { return j; }
};
```

Why do I get a compilation error on the line marked by `<--`? The compiler says that because `A` does not have a non-parameter constructor, but I would like to know exactly why the fact that `A` does not have a non-parameter constructor generates that error. Why is the error exactly on that line? I know how to change the code to work well, but I am preparing for an exam where we have to say which line produces the compilation error for a given piece of code. Thanks!

Comment: If you open your C++ textbook to the chapter that talks about constructors, and explains what the constructor's initialization section is, and what it is for, you will find the answer to all of the questions you asked. And it will likely have an example that's nearly identical to yours'.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I do not have a C++ textbook :(

Answer (score 3):

A **constructor runs its [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) before exectuing its body**.

So, when the `{j = x; a = y;}` part of your constructor gets a chance to execute, the data member `A a` already should have been initialized using its default constructor. And then, inside the body of the constructor, you **reassign** new value to it, in the `a = y` statement.

*You can (and in general should) use the solution proposed by [@CoryKramer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67936777/14624729), using the member initializer list. But you may also benefit from knowing that introducing the [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) (since the compiler won't synthesize one for you) to the `A` class can also be a valid option (depending on other factors).*

```
class A{
    int i;
public: 
    A() = default;
    A(int x): i(x){}
    int get_i(){return i;}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`A` has no default constructor, just a parameterized constructor, so you'd need to construct `B` using the member initialization list syntax

```
class B{
    A a;
    int j;
public:
    B(int x, A y) : j(x), a(y) {}
    int get_j(){return j;}
};
```

Comment: But why is the non parameters constructor called for A? Could you tell me please tell a more general rule ?

Comment: I mean, I know that in inheritance if the constructor is missing from initializer list the default (non-parameter) constructor of the base class will be called, is this the same rule ?

Comment: @alexMcKenzie the important thing to take away here is that you cannot initialize `A` in the body of the constructor. It is initialized before the constructor runs

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Is correct. Basically in your code *first* the (non existent) default constructor of `A` is called before the constructor body of `B` *then* you try to copy-assign `a` in the body of your `B` constructor.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, @CoryKramer So, if I have a class X that has another member objects, the non-parameter constructors of the embedded objects will be called before running the body of the the constructor ```X(...)```, unless they are initialized in the initializer list ?

Comment: @alexMcKenzie  Yes. All members for which you don't provide an initialiser are value initialised.